# How can I have multiple tor onions pointing to the same listening port

Tags: tor

So I am running a program which runs on a certain port.
I have a .onion domain pointing to that port the program is listening on.

I'm wanting to generate more .onion domains through tor but point them all to the same listening port my program is running on so I can enter any of the .onion domains and it will run my program like normal.

Is this possible?

I've seen that you can add multiple .onion domains but they seem to be pointing to different ports.
I just need multiple .onion domains pointing to the same port.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to create multiple onion services that point to the same port/application. To do this, create multiple HiddenService configurations with different data directories pointing to the same port:

*torrc*

```
# Hidden service instance 1
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hs-1/
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080

# Hidden service instance 2
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/hs-2/
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:8080
```

For each HiddenServiceDir/HiddenServicePort combination you create that points to the same port, you will get a different onion address which ultimately point to the same service.