# Running multiple services on different ports on the same onion domain?

Tags: service, port, tor

### Context

In some form the opposite of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64646146/7437143) question; how can one host multiple services on a single onion domain?

When I include:

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/gitlab/
HiddenServicePort 8070 127.0.0.1:8050
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/dash/
HiddenServicePort 9002 127.0.0.1:9001
```

and create the files

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/gitlabhostname
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/dash/hostname
```

Both hostnames will get an onion domain. Hence, I was wondering:

### Question

How can I ensure only 1 onion domain is created for both services? (`dash` and `gitlab` in this example).

### Note

I expect that I misunderstand the purpose of the `/var/lib/tor/<service_name>/ folder, and that perhaps the` /var/lib/tor/<service_name>/hostname` file is not required for (each) onion service. (In essence that it is only used to store e.g. some website data if needed). However, I did not yet figure out how this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can specify mutliple `HiddenServicePort` for one `HiddenServiceDir`, according to https://tor.stackexchange.com/a/4439

```
HiddenServiceDir /path/to/hs/dir/
HiddenServicePort 80 127.0.0.1:80
HiddenServicePort 8000 127.0.0.1:8000
HiddenServicePort 81 192.168.0.102:80
```